# using .NET to generate an AppStream URL

Tags: .net, aws-appstream

I have created a web application using dotnet core (.Net Core -- for Google) that looks up an email address in a database and then, if the email is found, should forward the user to an AppStream URL where I will be streaming an application. I would like the application being streamed to receive information from the login process just described.  My question is this:  does the streamed application have access to the query string variables of the streaming URL?  Or does it have access to a cookie left in the browser?